An action of $\Gamma_0(N)$ having finitely many orbits
For positive integers $m$ and $N$ let
\begin{align}
M_{2, m, N}(\mathbf{Z}) = \bigg\{\gamma \in M_2(\mathbf{Z}) \; \bigg\vert \; \det(\gamma) = m, \gamma \equiv \bigg(\begin{matrix} \ast & \ast \\ 0 & \ast \end{matrix}\bigg) \; \textrm{(mod $N$)}\bigg\}.
\end{align}
I know that the congruence subgroup
\begin{align}
\Gamma_0(N) = 
\bigg\{\gamma \in \textrm{SL}_2(\mathbf{Z}) \; \bigg\vert \; \gamma \equiv \bigg(\begin{matrix} \ast & \ast \\ 0 & \ast \end{matrix}\bigg) \; \textrm{(mod $N$)}\bigg\}
\end{align}
of $\textrm{SL}_2(\mathbf{Z})$ acts on $M_{2, m, N}(\mathbf{Z})$ by left-multiplication. I would like to show that there are finitely many right $\Gamma_0(N)$-orbits and to have some explicit set of orbit representatives.
Does anyone know how to do this or does anyone know a reference?
Edit: In Exercise 5.3.1 on page 181 of Diamond–Shurman's book they get (I think) the right $\Gamma_0(N)$-orbit representatives
\begin{align}
\bigg\{
\begin{pmatrix}
a & b \\
0 & d
\end{pmatrix}
\in
M_2(\mathbf{Z})
\;
\Big\vert
\;
ad = m, d > 0, \gcd(a, N) = 1, b \in \{0, \dots, d - 1\}
\bigg\}.
\end{align}
However when I play around with multiplying things in $M_{2, m, N}(\mathbf{Z})$ by things in $\Gamma_0(N)$, I can never seem to get something upper triangular (basically because I don't have the matrix $S = \begin{pmatrix} 0 & 1 \\ -1 & 0 \end{pmatrix}$ like in the $\textrm{SL}_2(\mathbf{Z})$ case).
This problem comes from writing down the action of the Hecke operator $T_m$ on the $\mathbf{C}$-points of the modular Jacobian $J_0(N)$.

In case it's useful, I think there should be $\sigma_1(m)$ right orbits where $\sigma_1$ is the divisor-sum function.
